# flutter: command not found

Tags: bash, flutter

I've just finished coding my very first Flutter app but I have a problem: I can't release the APK to publish the app.

I did all of the signing processes, which works properly, but when I write the command `flutter build apk`, the terminal says:

```
bash: flutter: command not found
```

After researching for I while I've discovered that the `PATH` is assigned to Python. That may be because few months I tried Python, but then I uninstalled it. But the Python thing is still is stuck in the Terminal, although the Python app is not in the Mac anymore, and it doesn't allow me to use flutter commands and indeed release the app.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you have said that you are trying to build an apk you are probably using android studio. If so you can build the apk from the build tab in it.

If you still want to add flutter to the paths you can follow [this](https://www.architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/)
link here to see how to add it to the path. Don't forget that you need to include flutters/bin folder in the path

Comment: Don't forget you need to open a new terminal for your path to be updated

Answer (score -1):

There is a section in the Flutter documentation how to set the PATH:

- [Windows](https://flutter.io/setup-windows/#update-your-path)
- [Mac OS](https://flutter.io/setup-macos/#update-your-path)

Comment: Yeah, I'm using a MacBook; and I had already followed those steps, and the PATH was updating for Python, not for Flutter. It's so weird.

Comment: Maybe just reinstall flutter from scratch?

Comment: Yeah, I'll probably do that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `export PATH="$PATH:[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/flutter/bin`